# React Boostrap Overlay

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

My code looks like this:

```js
{signupdata.username.length < 4 ? setShow(!show) : ""}
<Overlay target={target} show={show} placement="right">
  {(props) => (
    <Tooltip id="overlay-example" {...props}>  
      username must be at least 5 characters long
    </Tooltip>
  )}
</Overlay>
```

But everything disappears when the `username` reaches `5` characters.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of this part:

```
{signupdata.username.length < 4 ? setShow(!show) : ""}
```

it means that if `username.length` is lower then 4 `setShow(!show)` is changing `show` to `!show` and because you have `show={show}` overlay disappears after that.

Comment: U don't get it, EVERYTHING on screen dissapers

Comment: @DaBaby yes everything disappears because in the first part of your code you only show - "" and overlay is hidden because show is false